# add setTimeout to success function in ajax submit

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm able to get most of this right. On success an overlay div fades in with messages from the server. Obviously ".fadeOut(5000);" just fades it out over 5 seconds, what I need it to do is only stay visible for 5 seconds then fade out, but am not familiar with how to integrate a setTimeout function here, I appreciate any help!

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var txt = $("textarea#foo").val();
        var cont = $("#submitErrorOverlay p");
        txt = encodeURIComponent(txt);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: {foo:txt , action: 'foofunction'},
            success: function(result) {
        $('#submitErrorOverlay').fadeIn(500).html('<p>' + 'Congratulations' + result.msg + '<p>')****.fadeOut(5000);****
                $('textarea').val('');
            },
            error: function (data) {
            $('#msg').fadeIn(500).html('Awww Snaaap!' + data);
            $('textarea').val('');
        },
        dataType:'json'
});
```

EDIT apologies, I forgot about .delay - please disregard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `delay()`? http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$el.delay(5000).fadeOut('fast');
```